# How can I get my character to move along the correct axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Current Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBZYr.jpg)

Basically, I want to be able to move my character around in circles along the correct axis, I believe it's X? The picture above explains how I want it to move.

I want to recreate something along the lines of this: http://www.venusarcade.com/Tube-Racer.htm

It can currently move left and right but not like this ^

I guess it would also need to be able to go up and down to avoid obstacles.

What do you need from me to be able to recreate the script?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Also in that game you linked it seems that the level is moving instead.

Comment: I managed to get my plane model imported and move that like a plane would but it's not ideal - https://twitter.com/MouldyGaming/status/756461998284607488

Yeah it would seem that way, but I already have the movement of the player and have regenerating random platforms so it works the same :)

Comment: *What have you tried yourself?* is about the code that you have written so far. NOT how it looks like

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understand what you need but my first impression is that you want to use "RotateAround".
Documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Youtube Video explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3Whvf6V1xU

When you press horizontal keys(arrow keys or 'A' / 'D' ) you call the function to rotate.

Hope this helps.